# Executing a loop for a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

This is a very basic question and I'm sure it has been answered but I can't seem to find it elsewhere. I have a portion of vba code that works fine for a single cell. However I want to expand it to work for a range of cells (all within the same column).

Basically its a goalseeking loops that changes a value in the "b" column until the value in the "w" column matches (comes within 99%) the value in the "x" column.

What works:

```
Sub Goalseeker()

Do Until Range("w32").Value / Range("x32").Value > 0.99
    Range("b32").Value = Range("b32").Value - 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I want to extend this to work for rows 32 to 107.
What I've tried: 
Edit: I've made adjustment based on the comments received and tweaked and few things before it worked. If anyone is interested in the process:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Goalseeker()

Dim i As Integer
Dim targetcell As Double
Dim outputcell As Double
Dim variablecell As Range

For i = 32 To 107

targetcell = Cells(i, "x")
outputcell = Cells(i, "w")
Set variablecell = Range("B" & i)

Do Until outputcell / targetcell > 0.99
    variablecell = variablecell - 1
    targetcell = Cells(i, "x")
    outputcell = Cells(i, "w")
Loop

Next

End Sub
```

The bit I had to tweak was

```
Do Until outputcell / targetcell > 0.99
    variablecell = variablecell - 1
    targetcell = Cells(i, "x")
    outputcell = Cells(i, "w")
Loop
```

Redefining (i apologize if that's the wrong term) targetcell and outputcell was necessary to prevent an infinite loop.

Thanks all. I will work on making this function for relative references instead of absolute.

Comment: Change for i=32 to i=107, to for i=32 to 107

Comment: You also really need to get in the habit of declaring your variables. Put `Option Explicit` on the top of every module.

Comment: What if you never get to within 0.01 with step increments of 1.0?

Comment: Watch:[Excel VBA Introduction Part 16 - For Next Loops](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=JyWrLH7monI&index=18&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) and [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Answer (score 0):

Few problems here. Change your For i loop to the format `For i = x to y` not `For i = x to i = y`

You can refer to `targetcell` and `outputcell` as `double` but the `variablecell` needs to be a `range`. And if it's a `range` it needs `Set`

You should declare ALL your variables, as below.

And finally, you might want to put in a catch to get out of infinite looping (in case the target never reaches above 0.99 ?)

```
Sub Goalseeker()

Dim i As Integer

Dim targetcell As Double
Dim outputcell As Double
Dim variablecell As Range

For i = 32 To 107

    targetcell = Cells(i, "x")
    outputcell = Cells(i, "w")
Set variablecell = Range("B" & i)

    Do Until outputcell / targetcell > 0.99
        variablecell = variablecell - 1
    Loop

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: A few problems indeed.  `targetcell` and `outputcell` should not be integers. They are either values (`Double`) or ranges (`Range`).

Comment: Sorry yes, I was testing it with integers. Always forget to work with real numbers. Have edited the answer to remedy.

Comment: Thanks this was key. I had to make a little tweak to the "Do until" loop to stop it from looping infinitely...Not sure how to put code into a comment reply...

    Do Until outputcell / targetcell > 0.99
     variablecell = variablecell - 1
     targetcell = Cells(i, "x")
     outputcell = Cells(i, "w")
    Loop

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example table:

[image: table]

Use the code below to find the correct values in the "B" column (as shown) in order to minimize the error between the result (next column) and the goal (two columns over).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GoalSeekMyValues()

    ' Call GoalSeek with inputvalues "B2:B16", having the result
    ' at column offset 1, and the goal in column offset 2.
    ' Note that Range("B2").Resize(15, 1) = Range("B2:B16"),
    ' But I prefer the top cell and row count of this syntax.
    GoalSeek Range("B2").Resize(15, 1), 1, 2

End Sub

Public Sub GoalSeek(ByVal variables As Range, ByVal result_offset As Long, ByVal goal_offset As Long)
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, pct_error As Double, last_error As Double
    'x is the input value (variable)
    'y is the result
    'g is the goal for y
    Dim x As Double, y As Double, g As Double
    ' Read the number of rows in the input values
    n = variables.Rows.Count
    Dim r As Range
    ' Loop through the rows
    For i = 1 To n
        'Set a range reference at the i-th input cell
        Set r = variables.Cells(i, 1)
        ' Read the value, the result and the goal
        x = r.Value
        y = r.Offset(0, result_offset).Value
        g = r.Offset(0, goal_offset).Value
        pct_error = Abs(y / g - 1)
        Do
            'Set the next value
            r.Value = x - 1
            ' Read the result (assume goal doesn't change)
            y = r.Offset(0, result_offset).Value
            ' Keep last error, and calculate new one
            last_error = pct_error
            pct_error = Abs(y / g - 1)
            ' If new error is more than last then exit the loop
            ' and keep the previous value (with less error).
            If pct_error > last_error Then
                ' Keep last value
                r.Value = x
                Exit Do
            End If
            ' read the input value
            x = r.Value
            ' Assume inputs must be positive so end the loop
            ' on zero on negative numbers
        Loop Until x <= 0
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

Your code has *lots of points of failure*.

1. Your code might not ever reach a solution and excel will hang (until <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd> is pressed). I have a hard break when the inputs become zero or negative. Other problems require other ways to tell that there isn't a solution.
2. The first time the result comes within 1% of the solution *might not produce the least error*. I solve this by tracking the absolute value of the relative error. Only when the error starts increasing I terminate the loop. This assumes that decreasing the input **by one unit** will improve the solution (at least initially). If this is not the case the code will fail.
3. You use absolute referencing (like reading the 12th cell down and 4th across) and that is not very reusable style of programming. I **always** try to use relative referencing. I start from the top left referenced cell (in this case `B2`) and move down and right from there using the following methods:

   - `Range("B2").Cells(5,1)` - Reference 5th row and 1st column from `B2`.
   - `Range("B2").Resize(15, 1)` - Expand the range to include 15 rows and one column.
   - `Range("B2).Cells(i,1).Offset(0, 3)` - From the `i`-th row use column offset of 3 (meaning the 4th column in the table).
4. I suggest to use one of the common goal seeking methods (like bisection), or better yet, use the built-in goal seek function

example:

```
Range("B2").Cells(i,2).GoalSeek Goal:=Range("B2").Cells(i,3).Value, ChangingCell:=Range("B2").Cells(i,1)
```